# Trying to create negative nodejs (npm) long values

Tags: node.js

Below, Long.NEG_ONE produces the desired results.  What is the alternative way to construct a Long object using a negative value?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/long

`coffee> l=new Long "20000"
{ low: 20000,
  high: 0,
  unsigned: false }
coffee> (l.multiply Long.NEG_ONE).toString()
'-20000'
coffee> Long.NEG_ONE
{ low: -1,
  high: -1,
  unsigned: false }`

What is wrong with this (below)?  Why didn't `Long` not set the high value to -1 like above?

`coffee> new Long "-1"
{ low: -1,
  high: 0,
  unsigned: false }
coffee> (new Long "-1").toString()
'4294967295'
coffee> Long.NEG_ONE.toString()
'-1'`

Answer (score 0):

`new Long "2000"` is wrong.  Instead, use `Long.fromString "2000"`